# Do subsequent `observeOn` for the same scheduler cause re-queueing?

Tags: rx-java2, scheduler

Do subsequent `observeOn` for the same scheduler cause a re-queueing and are the subsequent transformation put into an own unit of work? Or is RxJava sufficiently intelligent to find out that the second `observeOn` is actually not required and merges/unfolds the transformations into a single synchronous unit of work?

Are

```
observable
  .observeOn( Schedulers.io )
  .map( ... )
  .map( ... )
  .last()
  .subscribe( ... )
```

and

```
observable
  .observeOn( Schedulers.io )
  .map( ... )
  .observeOn( Schedulels.io )
  .map( ... )
  .observeOn( Schedulers.io )
  .last()
  .observeOn( Schedulers.io )
  .subscribe( ... )
```

equivalent in terms of scheduling and execution efficiency or does the latter cause a new piece of work being re-scheduled for each `observeOn`?

Comment: Short answer: it will run 4 threads and 4 queues, thus inefficient. ObserveOn has to act as a barrier thus it is not allowed to simplify your second example.